# Adding two objects in Blender-python with a delay

Tags: python

Need your help.
I had written the following code

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector
import time

# Clear existing objects
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='MESH')
bpy.ops.object.delete()

# Add the first cube at the origin
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=1, location=(0, 0, 0))
cube1 = bpy.context.object

# Add the second cube after 2 seconds
time.sleep(2)
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=1, location=(4, 0, 0))
cube2 = bpy.context.object
```

I expect the code would work as follows:

1. Add a cube a the world origin
2. After 2 seconds, add a 2nd cube 4 units along the x-axis

Somehow, nothing happens when the script is executed, but appeared at the same time after 2 seconds

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code ?

Comment: Hello. time.sleep will stop blender's main loop altogether, so the interface won't update nor be responsive during this time. You have to use application timers for delaying your code https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html

Comment: Thanks mate. You're a life saver !!!!!